# Wood burning stove chimney leaking

Tags: roof, leak, roofing, chimney, flue

A house we bought a few years ago has a newly fitted wood burning stove and chimney. During combined heavy rain and high winds we will get water leaking down our inside wall near the stove.

I’m went up there last time this happened in 2020 and noticed there were a small gap between the tiles and the metal flashing of the chimney. My assumption was that the water was being blown in this gap causing the issue.

As a temporary measure I tried to pack these gaps with rolled up plastic sheets which worked for a while we were seeing the problem again now.

Is there anything else I should do to stop this? Do I need to get a professional in?

[[image: Where the water leaks][1]]

[image: showing where I stuffed the plastic]

Answer (score 2):

A normal fix for this would be to get some tile adhesive, roof sealer, and spread it over all the vent cap edges. Spread it under all the tile edges and also along the lower exposed edge of the cap. You've got a steep roof so if you feel comfortable working up there, this is a DIY type of project. If you don't feel comfortable, take some lessons from your cat or get some professional help.

Comment: Always good when the boss checks your work.